# The request is not being executed in rest controller test

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

I have a test method for one of the mappings where I provide all required data for the test

```
@Test
public void getAllMessagesNoFilterNotByTag() throws Exception {
    List<MessageDTO> messageDTOS = Arrays.asList(new MessageDTO(MESSAGE1), new MessageDTO(MESSAGE2));
    when(messageService.getAllMessages("", false,
          PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("creationDate").descending()))).thenReturn(messageDTOS);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/message?filter=&bytag=false&page=0"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(content().json(
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(new MessageDTO(MESSAGE1), new MessageDTO(MESSAGE2)))));
        verify(messageService, times(1)).getAllMessages("", false,
          PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("creationDate").descending()));
}
```

Here is the controller itself

```
@GetMapping
public List<MessageDTO> getAllMessages(@RequestParam(required = false) String filter,
      @RequestParam(name = "bytag", required = false) Boolean findByTag,
      @PageableDefault(sort = {"creationDate"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC, size = 5) Pageable pageable) {
      return messageService.getAllMessages(filter, findByTag, pageable);
}
```

But after running it I get this exception about failing to create Pageble object

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable - and no default constructor found either
    
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
        at com.training.vueblog.controllers.MessageControllerTest.getAllMessagesNoFilterNotByTag(MessageControllerTest.java:62)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable - and no default constructor found either
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:144)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        ... 74 more
```

Comment: The problem seems to come from the way the class which contains the endpoint 'getAllMessages' is built. Can you show us the declaration of this class and the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solve by adding extra configuration for mockMvc

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup(){
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(messageController)
    .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
    .build();
}
```